# Can't get first item from Single<List<T>>

Tags: android, kotlin, reactivex

In an android project, I have a statement like this:

```
import io.reactivex.Completable
import io.reactivex.Single

val itemsList: Single<List<T>> = getItems()
```

I need to get the first item from **itemsList**.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

As your `Single` is of type `List<Item>`, when you will fetch it on your `apiRepositoryObject` - your network layer object, you will either get single `List<Item>` or exception

```
apiRepositoryObject.getItems()
.subscribe(listOfItems -> {
    // The list of item should be handled here
},Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val itemsList: Single<List<T>> = getItems()

itemsList
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .map{list -> list.first()}
    .subscribeBy(
        onComplete = { firstItem -> {/* use your first item here */} },
        onError = { error -> {/* error handling */} }
    )
```